# How to move CCMenu in Cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a menu of two items - New game and Credits.
They are aligned vertically, like this:

```
New Game
Credits
```

When you click new game I want credits to shift down and open two new menu items, like that:

```
New Game
  Player vs Player
  Player vs AI
Credits
```

How do I do that? In my code menu just overwrites itself so I have those items on top of each other.

```
- (id) init
{
    if ([super init])
    {
        CCLayerColor *bg = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 255)];
        [self addChild:bg z:-1];


        CCMenuItemFont  *menu1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"New Game" target:self selector:@selector(callSecondMenu)];
        [menu1 setColor:ccc3(255, 255, 255)];

        CCMenuItemFont  *menu2 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Credits"];
        [menu2 setColor:ccc3(255, 255, 255)];

        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menu1, menu2, nil];
        [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:10];
        [self addChild:menu z:10];



    }
    return self;
}

- (void) callSecondMenu
{
    CCMenuItemFont *menu1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Player vs Player" target:self selector:@selector(callGame)];
    CCMenuItemFont *menu2 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Player vs AI" target:self selector:@selector(callGame)];
    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menu1, menu2, nil];
    [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:5];
    [self addChild:menu];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the menuItems as just characters in your game.

The way that I move menus in my games is to create each menu item in it's own separate CCMenu and set each CCMenu at position 0,0.

Then I manually position the CCMenuItemSprite/CCMenuItemFont menu items (not the CCMenu) using their position property at their start location and then use CCMoveTo action to move the menu items around when needed. This of course will work with any of the CCMenuItem subclasses, such as the CCMenuItemFont that you are using.

The downside of this approach is that you lose the ability to automatically align the menu items and they act as separate menus, but that is a small cost to the upside of being able to move the menu items around in any way to create interesting effects.

You can also use any other actions like CCFadeIn, CCSkewTo, CCScaleBy, etc to do cool effects on the individual menu items.

**1)** I create all of the menu items when the node that owns the menuItems is created. Then when each menu item is needed I animate it by moving or fading it into place.

**2)** I avoid using tags. This is just my preference. I prefer instead to create two NSMutableDictionary's as instance variables, one called menuButtons and one called menuButtonActions. Then I use helper functions to create the menuItems and actions and store them in the mutable dictionaries. Methods are then created for general things like buttonNamed:runActionNamed: and buttonNamed:setPosition:. These methods then use the two mutable dictionaries to retrieve the needed menuItem and action (when needed) and then apply the desired effect.

This might seem like more work, but if your game has several different situations where you have common menu buttons you want to show, then your code can be more readable and reusable because all you have to do is create your menu systems in the future using code like this:

```
-(void) showNewGameMenuExpanded:(BOOL)isExpanded {

    if(isExpanded){
        [menuNode buttonNamed:@"credits" runActionNamed:@"creditsSlideDown"];
        [menuNode buttonNamed:@"playerVsPlayer" runActionNamed:@"playerVsPlayerShow"];
        [menuNode buttonNamed:@"playerVsAi" runActionNamed:@"playerVsAiShow"];
    }else{
        [menuNode buttonNamed:@"credits" runActionNamed:@"creditsSlideUp"];
        [menuNode buttonNamed:@"playerVsPlayer" runActionNamed:@"playerVsPlayerHide"];
        [menuNode buttonNamed:@"playerVsAi" runActionNamed:@"playerVsAiHide"];
    }

}
```

This technique of building your buttons and actions on init of the menu node and storing them in dictionaries for use works great for things like pause menus or menus that slide in from the side of the screen to allow selecting different weapons, etc.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is some code added by Mazyod showing how to move a menu item by accessing the menu item using tags.

First, set the `tag` property to your `CCMenuItem`s:

```
    CCMenuItemFont  *menu1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"New Game" target:self selector:@selector(callSecondMenu)];
    [menu1 setColor:ccc3(255, 255, 255)];
    [menu1 setTag:1];

    CCMenuItemFont  *menu2 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Credits"];
    [menu2 setColor:ccc3(255, 255, 255)];
    [menu2 setTag:2];

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menu1, menu2, nil];
    [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:10];
    // add tag for the menu, or use instance variables:
    [self addChild:menu z:10 tag:kMenuTag];
```

Then, in your other method:

```
CCMenuItem* credits = [[self getChildByTag:kMenuTag] getChildByTag:2];
// apply the action ... It has been ages since I touched cocos2d:
[credits runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(0, 40)]];

CCMenuItemFont *menu1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Player vs Player" target:self selector:@selector(callGame)];
CCMenuItemFont *menu2 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Player vs AI" target:self selector:@selector(callGame)];
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menu1, menu2, nil];
[menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:5];
[self addChild:menu];
```

Comment: Exactly what Jim said. Let me add some code there, but I think you have to wait till moderation.